# Redirect rule when removing product from category

Tags: url-rewrite, product-urls, 301-redirect

I am looking for help on a redirect rule for magento. I have recently removed a lot of discontinued products out of product categories for example:

http://www.example.com/gym-wear-brands/golds-gym-long-sleeve/gym/top.html

I have now removed the above product out of the gym-wear-brands category and the URL is now showing a 404 page.

The direct product URL below still works:

http://www.example.com/golds-gym-long-sleeve-gym-top.html

Is there a redirect rule in `.htaccess` file that would allow me to remove all sub categories from URLs so all product URLs including category path would then then redirect to the product URL? I have around 7000 in WMT that need to be addressed.

Comment: There is nothing in the path that indicates to .htaccess that it contains a category. You would have to add a rule for every single retired product URL that redirects appropriately. Your best bet is an extension in Magento, which has the necessary context.

Answer (score 0):

To remove category paths from product url set "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" to "No" under System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations.

To remove parent category path from child category url 
Rewrite class Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
override method public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath) like below

```
public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
    {
        $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
        $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
        $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

        if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
            $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
            $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
        }

        if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
        }
        else {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
        }

        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
        // Code commented to remove parent category path from child category path
        //if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
                                                                           true, $category->getStoreId());

        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
            return $existingRequestPath;
        }

        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
            return $requestPath;
        }

        return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
                                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
        );
    }
```

**Modified below code**

```
if (null === $parentPath) {
            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        }
        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        }
to

//if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
```